# How do I combine these two shell commands into a Service?

Tags: automator

I run the following two commands on markdown files to get a nicely formatted PDF.

```
pandoc file.md -o file.html --css=markdown.css 
prince file.html file.pdf
rm file.html
```

How would I automate this? I'd like to right-click a markdown file, navigate to services, and choose convert markdown to PDF.

I know I should use `Automator` and I tried but couldn't link the right steps together. In my example above, file is the filename that needs to be the argument. I got as far as starting a new Automator service, choosing `Files & Folders`, and `Get Selected Finder Items` and got stuck there.

**Update**: Pandoc = http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/

Prince = http://www.princexml.com/

**Update #2 for clarity**

If I am in a folder with a markdown file named test.md,  then the complete command line syntax would be:

```
pandoc --from=markdown --to=html test.md --css=~path/to/css/markdown.css -o test.html
```

(Note: I have been able to automate this as a service and have named it Markdown to HTML)

Here is that code:

```
 for f in "$@"
 do 
/usr/local/bin/pandoc --from=markdown --to=html "$f" --css=/Users/fooo/Documents/Code/css/markdown.css -o "$f".html 
done
```

Now to convert that bit of html to PDF is something I am not able to link in. But the command line syntax for that would be:

```
prince test.html -o test.pdf
```

Comment: I have built the "RTF" equivalent service and, assuming nobody beats me to it, I'll post it when I get "back to my Mac". Meanwhile, let me toss an unsolicited plug for [Byword](http://bywordapp.com/) into the mix. I haven't touched that service in months.

Comment: `which pandoc`?

`which prince`? (As in what is the full path to each file)

Comment: This "prince" command -- is there an option for it to read from stdin? If so, this can be made quite easy through the magic of piping. If not, yes, this gets a little trickier.

Comment: path to pandoc/usr/local/bin/pandoc; path to prince: /usr/local/bin/prince

Comment: Sorry, one more: where does your markdown.css file live?

Comment: If you are making a Service, you don't need or want "Get Selected Finder Items." Whatever file is selected or right clicked is automatically passed to the workflow.

Comment: @Daniel: I added the actual syntax I would use if I were to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

What about an Automator service like this one:
[image]

The payload is the shell script

```
 for f in "$@"
 do
    pandoc "$f" --css=markdown.css | prince - "$f".pdf
 done
```

Whatever the selected file or files, the service runs them through `pandoc`'s Markdown parser, then takes the resulting html and processes it with `prince`, naming the output the original file name with a .pdf extension added.

The piping removes the need for you to manage temporary files.

Comment: make that `prince - "${f%.*}".pdf` to avoid files named `foo.md.pdf`. Also, you'll need a full path to `markdown.css`

Comment: Perfect! Just what I've been looking for. I've just added below the command that works for me using ```pandoc 2.4``` and which removes the ```.md``` from the pdf file name:
```for f in "$@"
 do
    pandoc -f markdown_mmd --wrap=preserve -V geometry:a4paper -o "${f/.md/}".pdf "$f"
 done```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Automator and create a new service:
[image: Create new service]
Then add a Shell Script:
[image: Shell script - automator]
Detailed information [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2011/03/howto-build-mac-os-x-services-with-automator-and-shell-scripting.ars)

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't answer my question. How does it know where to insert the input? In my case, pandoc $file_name -o $file_name.html --css=markdown.css (The script has to place the file_name as is in the first location, change extension to html in the second, but leave the --css-markdown.css argument alone).